# Auto pulling of data from sqlite to MS access using android

Tags: android, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm new in android and its kinda hard exporting data from sqlite to MS Access. Is it possible that there is a code for auto pulling of data from the emulator to MS Access?

Because I want the data from my sqlite database to be the same in my MS Access database.

Comment: Oops, I wanted to remove the VB.Net tag on this, because it has really nothing to do with VB.Net (possibly with vba?), but removed teh wrong tag... Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to link to SQLite from MS Access, but theoretically you should be able to, it may be because I have a slightly odd set-up on this machine. However, worst case scenario is get the table data and perform a row by row update to Access. You could automate this with Task Sceduler.

Some notes:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset


scn = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=z:\docs\new.db;" _
& "LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;"

cn.ConnectionString = scn
cn.Open

s = "SELECT * FROM test"
rs.Open s, cn

Debug.Print rs.GetString
```

References:
[Connection strings](http://connectionstrings.com)
[SQLite ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/)

May be of interest:
[SQLite for Excel](http://sqliteforexcel.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Sir thanks for your answer but this is just only the connection to vb.net to sqlite. Sir do you know any way that i can use to auto pull data from the emulators folder where my sqlite database it located?? :)